Meta-analyses with effect sizes from observational data - how to handle mutiple results from one study
I am hoping to perform my first meta-analysis using adjusted odds ratios and confidence intervals (using Stata).
I am specifically looking at one class of groups that has two subclasses.
I have these results from a cohort study:

Subclass I vs. unexposed: aOR 1.71 (0.78 – 3.78)
Subclass II vs. unexposed: aOR 2.17 (1.20 -3.91)
Subclass II vs. subclass I: aOR 1.27 (0.57 - 2.82)

Ideally I would like an odds ration for the overall class vs. unexposed, i.e. subclass I/subclass II vs. unexposed (assuming the subclasses are mutually exclusive).
I would really value advice if the above can be done or whether I should include both results from 1) and 2) above (although I am assuming this might give too much weight to this individual study).
Many thanks!
